# How do I make a table cell clickable in this JavaScript generated table?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How do I make a table cell click able in this JavaScript generated table?

I think where I've placed the comment in the script tag is where I need to change the code.

This code works so far:

```
function createTable(data) {
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.style.border = "1px solid #ffcc33";
    var thead = document.createElement("thead");
    thead.style.padding = "5px";
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var i = 0;i < data[0].length; i++){
            var th = document.createElement("th");
            th.style.border = "2px solid #ff0000";
            var newText = document.createTextNode(data[0][i]);
            // maybe an onclick goes here!
            th.appendChild(newText);
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }
        thead.appendChild(tr);
        table.appendChild(thead);
        
        var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
        for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++){
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            for(var j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){  
                var td = document.createElement("td");
                td.style.padding = "5px";
                td.style.border = "2px solid #00ff00";
                var newText = document.createTextNode(data[i][j]);
                td.appendChild(newText);
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            tbody.appendChild(tr);
            }
            table.appendChild(tbody);               return table;
        
  }
  window.onload = function() {
        var table = createTable ([
        ["1","2","3","4"],
        ["One","Two","Three","Four"],
        ["Un","Deux","Trois","Quatre"],
        ["eins","zwei","drei","vier"]
        ]);
        document.body.appendChild(table)
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you opposed to jquery?

You could try adding jquery to the header and adding

```
$(newText).click(function(){
     //do stuff
});
```

Comment: Please don't post jQuery-only answers to non-jQuery questions.

Comment: That's why I prefaced my answer with "are you opposed to jquery?"  I usually don't post jquery if the poster requests pure javascript only

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you *could* hook up `click` on each and every `th` element where you've put that comment:

```
if (th.addEventListener) {
    // Standard
    th.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}
else if (th.attachEvent) {
    // IE8 and earlier
    th.attachEvent('onclick', function(e) {
        return clickHandler.call(this, e || window.event);
    });
}
```

...but your best bet is probably to use event delegation. Hook `click` on the `thead` element (since you only want the `th`s):

```
if (thead.addEventListener) {
    // Standard
    thead.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}
else if (thead.attachEvent) {
    // IE8 and earlier
    thead.attachEvent('onclick', function(e) {
        return clickHandler.call(this, e || window.event);
    });
}
```

...and then look at the `target` property on the event object passed into `clickHandler`. That will be the element on which the click actually occurred (some descendant of the `thead`, or the `thead` itself).

If you only care about `th` clicks, the handler might look something like this:

```
function clickHandler(e) {
    var target = e.target, th;
    while (target && target !== this) {
        if (target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "TH") {
            th = target;
            break;
        }
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    if (th) {
        // It's a th, do something
    }
}
```

The same technique can be very handy for handling clicks on cells in the table body. Obviously you capture those either on the `tbody` or the `table` itself, however you want to handle it.

---

Note that this can be a **lot** simpler if you can use a decent JavaScript DOM library, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

For instance, the event delegation example in jQuery:

```
$(thead).on('click', 'th', function(e) {
    // It's a th, handle it
});
```

No IE-checking, and the delegation handling is done for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think event delegating is better in case of dynamic dom.
And separating DOM and eventHandler is better too.

```
// or attachEvent, you have to handle corss browsers.
table.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.tagName === 'TD') {
      alert(evt.target.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

so, you can add EventHander to your table(or target DOM) and then when event occur, you can check where event is occured from and choose action depends on DOM.

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/outsider/nd5FX/).